# Firebase Cloud Function .onWrite always logs null or undefined

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm at a loss about why this won't log anything but "null" or "undefined" to the console. I'm testing this from the Google Cloud Platform testing browser interface. I've also tried logging EVENT (instead of CHANGE and CONTEXT) with the same result. I have also tried opening the security rules, but that also didn't help. Any advice is highly appreciated.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.fanOutLink = functions.database.ref('/userLink/BLAH584H5BLAH30BLA/link').onWrite((change, context) => {
  console.log('value is:'+change.before.val());
});
```

And here is the JSON I'm using to test the code above:

```
{
"userLink": {
      "BLAH584H5BLAH30BLA": {
        "link": "https://blabla.com"
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are *changing* data, and not adding/deleting it? `change.before` will only have a value on updates/deletes. On writes of new data it will be an empty snapshot.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, I'm positive I'm changing the link value. The Google Cloud Platform test interface Output is: Error: function execution failed. Details: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined

Comment: I'm actually not sure if the GCP test interface invokes Firebase's functions with the parameters you expect . Hopefully somebody else can confirm that.

Comment: I'd suggest that you make sure your function works the way you expect when deployed with the Firebase CLI using an actual change to the database **before** you play with in in the GCP test interface.  I'm not certain that test interface will work the way you expect for Firebase events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Cloud Function **must** always return a Promise (or if you cannot, at least a value).

Your function should work as is but with a delay and an error in the log like "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value". It may happen that the Cloud Functions instance running your function shuts down before your function successfully write the message in the log.

If you change your code as follow you will get a (quasi) instant reply:

```
exports.fanOutLink = functions.database.ref('/userLink/BLAH584H5BLAH30BLA/link').onWrite((change, context) => {
    console.log('value is:'+change.before.val());
    return true;
});
```

I would suggest you have a look at those 2 videos from the Firebase team: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=511s and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk&t=37s

---

Following our "discussion" in the comments below, it appears that you use the new Cloud Functions syntax but with an old version of the library. Look at this documentation item: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff, and do as indicated, before redeploying:

> Run the following in the functions folder:
>
> `npm install firebase-functions@latest --save`
>
> `npm installfirebase-admin@5.11.0 --save`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated the code but it still returns the following: 
"Error: function execution failed. Details: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined"

Comment: Which version of Cloud Functions are you using? You can find it in the package.json file under the "dependencies"/ node, "firebase-functions" element

Comment: "firebase-admin": "~5.4.0" and "firebase-functions": "^0.7.0"

Comment: The error you are getting is normal: your syntax (`onWrite((change, context)`) is the one of Cloud Functions above version 1.0. Do what is explained at the beginning of this documentation item: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff, i.e. the two npm install. I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. I should have checked that.

Comment: @luciusdegeer Would you mind upvoting the answer if you think it is useful. Thanks